# What do we call a person who wants to park his/her vehicle?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I know Valet, the person takes our vehicle and parks it on our behalf. Valet parking is a word derived from that. But then, if I want to park my vehicle in the parking lot by myself, what am I called? Wanna-be ______.

> In other words, I want to know the word for the person who wants to park his/her vehicle in the parking.

'Parker' is not a proper word, right? Please answer.

Comment: There is no single word whose meaning is  "the driver of a vehicle who wants to park it in a parking lot himself".

Comment: Generally, you'd still refer to that person as the "driver," even after he has parked the car and left it behind, as in, "Do you know who the driver of the car parked over there is?"  Note that @Tᴚoɯɐuo used exactly that word the first comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a special term for that in English, but if we're talking about public places like shopping malls, restaurants, hotels etc., you could always refer to people who park their cars by themselves as [**self-parking customers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valet_parking):

> Valet parking is a parking service offered by some restaurants, stores, and other businesses, there is Valet Parking in all parts of the world. In contrast to **"self-parking"**, where customers find a parking space on their own, customers' vehicles are parked for them by a person called a valet. This service either requires a fee to be paid by the customer or is offered free of charge by the establishment.